# Implement inner join using simple nested loop in Java

Tags: java, join

I have been asked in an interview about how to implement Inner Join using nested for loop in Java. I found on internet about Hash Join here https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hash_join but couldn't find anything on internet explaining about simple nested loop implementation of inner join. I tried implementing the code but got stuck at few places as mentioned in the code comment.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param R
 * @param index1 Join column for table R.
 * @param S
 * @param index2 Join column for table S.
 * @return
 */
public String[][] innerJoin(String[][] R, int index1, String[][] S, int index2) {
    // How to define the result array. What should be it's size?? Is the below code correct.
    String[][] result = new String[R.length + S.length][R[0].length + S[0].length];

    // loop through both the tables to find out when the join column have common values.
    // output those common values.
    for (int i = 0; i < R.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < S.length; j++) {
            if (R[i][index1] == S[j][index2]) {
                // How to combine both tables here ???
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

)

Comment: So you don't know what inner join is, or how to implement it in Java? Without the first, you cannot do the second.

Comment: I certainly know what inner join is. But have a hard time implementing it in java. Any help in that direction would be helpful.

Comment: What is you implementation then? Just paste your code and we will help you find a solution.

Comment: The link you've mentioned for hash join has it's java implementation, check it out here: https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Hash_join#Java

Comment: @Darshan: Yes, that is a hash join implementation. This question is for Nested loop join implementation in java.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly identified 3 important issues in the question code:

- how do you calculate the size of the result table?
- how do you find matches?
- when you find a match, how do you add it to your result table?

The easy way to calculate the result is to store matches somewhere else, and then count how many you have found before returning them. In this sense, it would be better to use `ArrayList<String[]>` instead of `String[][]`, because you can append to `ArrayLists` but cannot change the size of arrays.

Finding matches with a double-loop is indeed very inneficient `O(nm)`, but hey, if that is what they want, it can certainly be done. It would be a lot easier to sort on the indices first and then work on that (`O(n log n + m log m + n log m)`, with O(n+m) extra memory); or build hashtables and use them (`O(n + m + n) = O(n + m)`).

Choosing what to return depends on what the columns represent, and if there are any duplicates. You could, for example, decide on the following format:

- as 1st column, the contents of `index1`
- all columns (except `index1` one) from the 1st table
- all the columns (except `index2`) from the second table.

Note that the choice of format is somewhat arbitrary; you could have left `index1` in its place, and then just ommit it from the columns of table 2. In any case, with the previous answers, you would get:

```
public String[][] innerJoin(String[][] R, int index1, String[][] S, int index2) {
    // temporary storage for matches
    ArrayList<String[]> matches = new ArrayList<>();

    // loop through both the tables to find out when the join column have common values.
    // output those common values.
    for (int i = 0; i < R.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < S.length; j++) {
            if (R[i][index1] == S[j][index2]) {
                matches.add(combine(R[i], S[j], index1, index2));
            }
        }
    }

    // convert matches to expected output array
    return matches.toArray(new String[matches.size()][]);
}

private String[] combine(String[] one, String[] two, int index1, int index2) {
    String[] r = new String[one.length + two.length - 1];
    int pos = 0;
    r[pos ++] = one[index1];
    for (int i=0; i<one.length; i++) if (i != index1) r[pos ++] = one[i];
    for (int i=0; i<two.length; i++) if (i != index2) r[pos ++] = two[i];
    return r;
}
```

Comment: It solved my problem. But for correctness, you should change the second for loop of the combine method to r[pos ++] = two[i];

Comment: fixed the `one[i]` -> `two[i]`

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give you some hints:

- The length for the result array is not the sum of the length of R and S tables. Depending on the contents of the tables, it could be up to `R.length * S.length`.
- The number of "columns" in the result array is indeed `R[0].length + S[0].length` (as long as the arrays are "real" tables and do not have variable number of "columns" per "row").
- In your loop (in the `if` block), you should

  - In the current "output" line of the result array (starting with 0), set first `R[0].length` columns (0..rl - 1) to the contents of the `R[i][0] ... R[i][rl - 1]` columns
  - Then, set the `rl ... R[0].length + S[0].length - 1` columns (rl ... rl + sl - 1) to the contents of the `S[j][0] ... S[j][sl - 1]` columns
  - Increment a counter for the current "output" line in the result array

In the end, it is just some array offset arithmetics ;-)